# Memory Leaks in Irregularly Shaped UIButtons

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

I know this is a long-shot, but since I need this code to work, maybe someone here can help.

I'm using the [Irregularly Shaped Buttons](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/iPhone/IrregularlyShapedButtons.aspx) code from CodeProject.com in one of my iPhone apps.  Works great, but Instruments is reporting two memory leaks.  I'm using the code in a standard UIViewController, but that is inside a UINavigationController, which might be where the problems lie.

The first leak is reported in the myInit method of **clickThruButton.m**

```
- (void) myInit
{
    // Set so that any alpha > 0x00 (transparent) sinks the click
    uint8_t threshold = 0x00;
    self.alphaMask = [[AlphaMask alloc]  initWithThreshold: threshold]; 
    [self setMask];
}
```

I can see the release down below, so I'm not sure why this would leak:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [self.alphaMask release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Perhaps we first need to check to see if self.alphaMast is nil before doing the alloc?

The second is at the end of the calcHitGridFromCGImage method in **AlphaMask.m**:

```
// COPIES buffer
// is AUTORELEASED!
// http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/
// MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH
NSData* ret = [NSData dataWithBytes: (const void *) dest 
                             length: (NSUInteger) destBytes ];

CGContextRelease (alphaContext);
free (alphaGrid);
free (dest);

return ret;
```

The leak appears on the NSData assignment.  There's no alloc, new or copy, so where's the leak?

I would **REALLY** appreciate any help you could provide here.  I know it's a stretch, but I need this to work ASAP.  Thanks!

**UPDATED:**

The full source can be found at the link above, but this may help clear up the alphaMask definition:

```
//
//  ClickThruButton.h
//  Test
//
//  Pi

@class AlphaMask;

@interface clickThruButton : UIButton 
{
    @private AlphaMask* _alphaMask;
}

@end
```

and...

```
//
//  ClickThruButton.m
//  Test
//
//  Pi

#import "clickThruButton.h"
#import "AlphaMask.h"

@interface clickThruButton ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) AlphaMask* alphaMask;

- (void) myInit;
- (void) setMask;

@end

@implementation clickThruButton

@synthesize alphaMask = _alphaMask;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(1)**

The `alphaMask` property is likely set to `-retain`. This causes the retain count to increase by 1 automatically when set. But `[AlphaMask alloc]` already returns an object with retain count of +1, so the overall retain count is excessively +2.

The `[self.alphaMask release]` later can only decrease the retain count by 1, so finally the count cannot get to 0 and deallocate, i.e. the memory will be leaked.

You should rewrite that as

```
AlphaMask* mask = [[AlphaMask alloc]  initWithThreshold: threshold];
self.alphaMask = mask;
[mask release];        // cancel the retain.
```

**(2)**

I don't think there's any leak in this piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

`self.alphaMask = [[AlphaMask alloc]  initWithThreshold: threshold];` is likely a leak. Without seeing the definition of that property I can't say for sure though.